# Gazebo parse problem with Groovy

Tags: gazebo, groovy

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I have just installed ros-groovy and when I try to run the gazebo example:

```
roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch
```

there is no problem, but if I try to lauch any of the other examples with:

```
roslaunch gazebo_worlds office_world.launch
```

I have some errors:

```
Msg Waiting for master.Warning [parser.cc:377] SDF has no <sdf> element in
file[/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/worlds/simple_office.world]
Error:   Could not find the 'robot' element in the xml file
         at line 59 in
/tmp/buildd/ros-groovy-urdfdom-0.2.7-0precise-20130326-0224/urdf_parser/src/model.cpp
Error [parser_urdf.cc:1814] Unable to call parseURDF on robot model
Warning [parser.cc:377] SDF has no <sdf> element in file[urdf file]
Error [parser.cc:291] parse as old urdf model file failed.
Error [Server.cc:253] Unable to read sdf
file[/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/worlds/simple_office.world]
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 29155, exit code 139, cmd
/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/scripts/gazebo
/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/worlds/simple_office.world
__name:=gazebo
__log:=/home/tseco/.ros/log/a6bdf53c-eae5-11e2-9efd-3cd92b6f7a37/gazebo-2.log].
log file:
/home/tseco/.ros/log/a6bdf53c-eae5-11e2-9efd-3cd92b6f7a37/gazebo-2*.log
```

The gazebo version installed is 1.5.

Any suggestions?

Best regards,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3705/gazebo-parse-problem-with-groovy/) by [tseco](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/427/tseco/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-07-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It looks like the `gazebo_worlds` package in ROS Groovy contains some very old `.world` files that use a syntax that's no longer supported.  Specifically, these `.world` files will fail to parse:

```
3stacks.world
balcony.world
camera.world
elevator.world
empty_listener.world
grasp.world
scan.world
simple_erratic.world
simple_office_table.world
simple_office.world
simple.world
test_friction.world
wg.world
```

So you should avoid using those `.world` files, including the `.launch` files that refer to them.

Note that the `simulator_gazebo` stack (which contains the `gazebo_worlds` package) has been deprecated starting in ROS Groovy and will no longer be distributed in ROS Hydro.

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tseco](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/427/tseco/) on 2013-07-24**:
Thank you very much for your answer. Is it possible to use urdf files with gazebo and groovy or only sdf files?

**Comment by [tseco](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/427/tseco/) on 2013-07-24**:
Thank you very much.

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-07-24**:
Yes you can use URDF files with gazebo.